# Segmentation fault on vector pushback

Tags: c++

I'm trying to fill a vector with strings of user input and every time I run the program and call the function I get a segmentation fault no matter what I input. I'm fairly inexperienced and any input is appreciated. The issue is in my entry() function, every time I try to input a string my program crashes. I'd like to know why I see a segmentation fault at the same location every time. Am I missing something obvious?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

class Interface   
{
private:
    std::vector<std::string> storage;
    std::vector<bool> flag;
int i;
std::string temp;
//temp
int t;
public:
void entry();
void display();
void remove();
void complete();
void exit();
void recursiveBonus();

};

void Interface::entry()
{
i = 0;
do
{
    std::cout << "Please enter a task:" << std::endl;
    getline(std::cin, temp);
    storage.push_back(temp);
    flag.push_back(false);
    i++;
}while(storage[i] != " ");
};
```

Comment: `std::vector<std::string> storage (" ");` doesn't compile for me

Comment: Oops, sorry! I've been trying a bunch of things to get it to work thought initialization might help but I've removed that since and fixed it in the code posted here. Still gets the fault on run.

Comment: You logic seems a bit flawed for the loop. I assume you want to end the loop when an empty string was entered? Then you should check for that. I.e. `if (temp.empty()) { break; }`

Comment: As for your problem, use a debugger to find out *where* the crash happens in your code. When you catch the crash "in action" in the debugger, you can check the values of involved variables to see if they look okay. One thing you really need to check is if `this` is a null pointer.

Comment: Lastly another thing: The variable `temp` and `i` should not be member variables, but local variables inside the `entry` function. Even if you use them in other function they should be local variables there too.

Comment: Thanks! Changing the loop conditions fixed it Joachim. I'm still learning all the resources that are available but that worked like a charm. Still seeing faults in other functions but I won't ask people to rake my entire code, this should be enough for me to go on. Guess I need to brush up on vectors!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `storage` is empty when entering `entry()`:

Consider the first loop iteration. Initially `i == 0`, then you read a string and `push_back` it into `storage`. Then you increment `i`. Now `i == 1`.
Then the loop condition is checked for which `storage[i]`, i.e. `storage[1]` is accessed. Index 1 represents the second element in the vector, but you have only inserted one!
Therefore you have undefined behavior here, which is likely the reason for the segmentation fault.

Also, if you want to check that the last thing entered is empty, you need to test against `""`, not `" "`. The latter is not an empty string but one with one space. See the question's comments for other advice.

Comment: Both of you had helpful feedback, thank you! Seems like I just have logical errors scattered about that I need to revisit.